# tp-link wireless usb adapter doesn't have IP

Tags: ip, ifconfig, tp-link

I've added a new TP-LINK TL-WN722N to my 20.04.1-Ubuntu, but when I run `ifconfig` I don't get an IP for it, only the MAC address:

```
wlxb4b02434988b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether b4:b1:34:54:98:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Do you know why I don't get any IP?

Comment: We don't know why you don't get an IP. It depends on where you are supposed to get an IP from ;-)

Comment: When you click on the Network Manager icon at the top right, do you see networks? What happens when you click on yours and try to connect?

Comment: Are you sure of the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: @David yes I ran uname -a

Comment: Then you have a very out of date system. An up to date system would be 20.04.5

Comment: @chili555 Yes I am connected to my home wifi with the wireless card of my laptop